# webhook MS Teams integration with Prometheus - request failed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, alertmanager

I'm struggling with Microsoft Teams/Prometheus integration on K8s cluster.
I used helm to start all components.
I have correctly working Prometheus and Alertmanager. It seems that all works fine. Prometheus communicate with Alertmanager. Then prometheus-msteams receives POST alert from Alert Manager and it should send it to a Microsoft Teams Channel but it's not.

```
2022/03/01 06:49:38 [DEBUG] POST https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx-xxx-xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx
2022/03/01 06:50:08 [ERR] POST https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx-xxx-xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx request failed: Post https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx-xxx-xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx: dial tcp 42.12.12.542:443: i/o timeout
```

30s and timeout.
I thought that it may be a proxy issue.
So I added extraEnv parameter to config map, restarted pod but nothing changed.
So my configuration looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  connectors.yaml: |
    connectors:
      - alertmanager-warning: https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx-xxx-xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx
      - alertmanager-critical: https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx-xxx-xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx

    extraEnvs:
      HTTPS_PROXY: http://my-proxy.com:911
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
```

I also loged into container to check if /etc/config/connectors.yaml is OK.
I'm afraid that this extraEnvs doesn't work somehow.
From K8s worker node I tried manually (with curl) post some test json to MS Chanel and without proxy it hanged. When I exported HTTPS_PROXY var the message was sucessfully created in MS Teams Chanel.

```
 export HTTPS_PROXY=http://my-proxy.com:911
 curl -X POST -d @test.json https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx-xxx-xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx
```

Do you have any idea what can cause the problem? Is this HTTPS_PROXY env should be listed when I type *printvenv* in prometheus-msteams container?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :)
HTTPS_PROXY should be defined deployment not configMap

```
env:
  - name: HTTPS_PROXY
    value: http://myproxy.com:911
```